# Original Poems from Notes from the City of the Sun

Tags: poetry, identification-request, chinese-language, bonnie-s-mcdougall, notes-from-the-city-of-the-sun

I am interested in finding the original Chinese poems used in *Notes from the City of the Sun* by Bonnie S. McDougall. I know the poems are from Bei Dao, and, according to [this webpage](https://user.guancha.cn/main/content?id=350858), the poems used include "生活" (translates to Living), "艺术" (translates to Art), "命运" (translates to Fate), "祖国" (translates to Motherland), and "自由" (translates to Freedom). However, there appears to be 14 poems total, and and all I could find was "生活," found on the previously linked site as it was only one word long (网, meaning net) and the second line of "命运" from [this webpage](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/10877564.html) (栏杆随意敲打着夜晚, [translating to The railing randomly knocks on the night](https://www.deepl.com/translator#zh/en/%E6%A0%8F%E6%9D%86%E9%9A%8F%E6%84%8F%E6%95%B2%E6%89%93%E7%9D%80%E5%A4%9C%E6%99%9A)). Could someone help me find the rest, or at least provide some tips, like certain search terms, or a website that has these works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original Chinese title is 太阳城札记.

> **生命**
>
> 太阳也上升了
>
> **爱情**
>
> 恬静。雁群飞过
> 荒芜的处女地
> 老树倒下了，嘎然一声
> 空中飘落着咸涩的雨
>
> **自由**
>
> 飘
> 撕碎的纸屑
>
> **孩子**
>
> 容纳整个海洋的图画
> 叠成了一只白鹤
>
> **姑娘**
>
> 颤动的虹
> 采集飞鸟的花翎
>
> **青春**
>
> 红波浪
> 浸透孤独的桨
>
> **艺术**
>
> 亿万个辉煌的太阳
> 呈现在打碎的镜子上
>
> **人民**
>
> 月亮被撕成闪光的麦粒
> 播在诚实的天空和土地
>
> **劳动**
>
> 手，围拢地球
>
> **命运**
>
> 孩子随意敲打着栏杆
> 栏杆随意敲打着夜晚
>
> **信仰**
>
> 羊群溢出绿色的洼地
> 牧童吹起单调的短笛
>
> **和平**
>
> 在帝王死去的地方 
> 那支老枪抽枝、发芽 
> 成了残废者的拐杖
>
> **祖国**
>
> 她被铸在青铜的盾牌上
> 靠着博物馆发黑的板墙
>
> **生活**
>
> 网

Excerpt from the Chinese poetry website [shigeku.com](http://www.shigeku.com/shiku/xs/beidao/108.htm). Notice that 生命, 爱情, 自由... are all the titles of the poems.

Comment: Nice answer! Could you provide some pointers as to how you doing this information? That way other people can become better at searching for themselves :)

Comment: @bobble Search "栏杆随意敲打着夜晚"(with quotation marks) directly in Google. Then look for results containing "太阳城".

Comment: Thank you.
@SyzygyYuan, how would I know to search for results containing "太阳城"?

Comment: @bobble When you browse through the results you will find the word 太阳, and then you can guess it is the title of the poems because it fits the English title "Sun"